# Ошибка с TeleBot в telebot

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot

Первый раз пишу телеграмм-бота, уже написал простейший код, пробую его запустить, но Python выдает ошибку: AttributeError: partially initialized module 'telebot' has no attribute 'TeleBot' (most likely due to a circular import). Я уже искал решения в гугле, но там говорят что нужно удалить если есть модуль telebot, и установить pytelegrambotapy. Я все так и сделал, перезапустил пк, но ошибка никуда не исчезла. Помогите пожалуйста, буду очень благодарен!

Вот код:

```
import telebot

bot = telebot.TeleBot("Токен")

@bot.message_handler(content_types = ["text"])
def hell_text(message):
    if message.text.upper() == "ПРИВЕТ":
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Привет!")

bot.polling(none_stop = True, interval = 0)
```

Comment: можно полный `Traceback`

Comment: есть подозрение что файл со скриптом называется telebot.py

Comment: Да, файл называется telebot.py

Comment: переименуйте и попробуйте еще раз

Comment: Переименование не помогает, я даже создал новый файл, и тоже самое

Comment: попробуйте повторить в  виртуальную среду myvenv если создавали ее

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте, быть может, поможет.

```
pip uninstall telebot
pip install pytelegrambotapi
```

Comment: *Я уже искал решения в гугле, но там говорят что нужно удалить если есть модуль telebot, и установить pytelegrambotapy. Я все так и сделал, перезапустил пк, но ошибка никуда не исчезла.*

Comment: @Vadim.Sharoikin Ваш код работает у меня. Вы можете добавить новую ошибку?

Comment: у меня тоже работает, просто процитировал автор, который вроде как делал эти действия

Comment: Спасибо за ваш ответ, все работает

Comment: @Яяя Пожалуйста, отметь мой ответ как правильный(галочкой)